# How to debug ember integration test with Webstorm

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, webstorm, ember-cli, qunit

I'm trying to debug a qunit ember integration test on Webstorm. Qunit is the same framework that ember is tested with.

Our test is similar to this:

```
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
var App;
module('Integration Tests', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
});

test("Checking hub page",function(){
    expect(2);
    visit('/hub');

    andThen(function(){
        console.log(currentRouteName());
        ok('in to the function');
    });
});
```

I am trying these settings:

[image]

Edit------------------------------

I updated my run config but the application exits with the following error:

```
debugger listening on port 59771
version: 0.1.7
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...Building...

Build successful - 1853ms.
c[?25l[8;NaNrtty.setRawMode: Use `process.stdin.setRawMode()` instead.

tty.js:37
    throw new Error('can\'t set raw mode on non-tty');
          ^
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to debug your tests? I'd love to know the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have used ember to run your code. And you are running it as a simple node.js application (`node foo-test.js`). Moreover, Node won't accept EcmaScript 6 syntax unless being run with --harmony switch. Please make sure to update your run configuration accordingly (to run ember and pass your spec as a parameter to it)

Comment: sorry how do I run it as a ember app?

Comment: I have an application params input in the run config that is blank, do I put the ember test foo.js command there?

Comment: you need to specify a path to node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember as a 'javascript file' and 'test -s' as application parameters.

Comment: thanks, I now get: **Build successful - 2060ms.
c[?25l[8;NaNrtty.setRawMode: Use `process.stdin.setRawMode()` instead.**

Comment: this message comes from node.js - it just means that tty.setRawMode is deprecated - http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html

Comment: thanks but how can I resolve this, please see my edit

Comment: you can't resolve it - nodejs console in Webstorm is non-tty, because node process is started with input/output streams redirection. Please follow [WEB-1933](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933) for updates

Comment: I think this issue is fixed now on github :)